# Is there a way to keep ajax calls from firing off seemingly sequentially in web2py?

Tags: ajax, web2py

I'm developing an SPA and find myself needing to fire off several (5-10+) ajax calls when loading some sections. With web2py, it seems that many of them are waiting until others are done or near done to get any data returned.

Here's an example of some of Chrome's timeline output

[image: example]

Where green signifies time spent waiting, gray signifies time stalled, transparent signifies time queued, and blue signifies actually receiving the content.

These are all requests that go through web2py controllers, and most just do a simple operation (usually a database query). Anything that accesses a static resource seems to have no trouble being processed quickly.

For the record, I'm using sessions in cookies, since I did read about how file-based sessions force web2py into similar behavior. I'm also calling session.forget() at the top of any controller that doesn't modify the session.

I know that I can and I intend to optimize this by reducing the number of ajax calls, but I find this behavior strange and undesirable regardless. Is there anything else that can be done to improve the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using cookie based sessions, then requests are not serialized. However, note that browsers limit the number of concurrent connections to the same host. Looking at the timeline output, it does look like groups of requests are indeed made concurrently, but Chrome will not make all 21 requests concurrently.

If you can't reduce the number of requests but must make them all concurrently, you could look into [domain sharding](https://www.maxcdn.com/one/visual-glossary/domain-sharding-2/) or configuring your web server to use [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2).

As an aside, in web2py, if you are using file based sessions and want to unlock the session file within a given request in order to prevent serialization of requests, you must use `session.forget(response)` rather than just `session.forget()` (the latter prevents the session from being saved even if it has been changed, but it does not immediately unlock the file). In any case, there is no session file to unlock if you are using cookie based sessions.

Comment: We tried switching to HTTP/2 and while certain implementations (IIS) were dramatically faster than others (nginx with uwsgiemperor), the shape of the requests remains the same. i.e., the timeline output in Chrome still looks generally like a stairstep as each request returns in succession. Is there anything else we could look into?  [example](http://i.imgur.com/55qoXfg.png)

Comment: In the new example, it looks like the requests are being fired off concurrently, but the server isn't processing more than one or two at a time. In your web server configuration, how many processes/threads have you specified. You may need to configure more workers so multiple requests can be served concurrently.